# Can Hibernate automatically recognize an entity type?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm creating project using Hibernate and Spring Data JPA. I have one superclass named Product (with fields like price etc) and some specialized subclasses like Memory, Processor with specialized fields (different for all classes). All products have separate tables.

My question is: can i use all products polimorphically - like

```
  productRepository.update(product)
```

and will hibernate automatically detect type od product (so it can save object to appropriate table)?
I used

```
@MappedSuperclass and @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

annotations in my `Product class` - is this enough?

Comment: i think hibernate can use `getClass()` to determine class, so give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate inheritance mapping support is suitable for this scenario. In your example, you don't have to call:

```
productRepository.update(product);
```

unless you want to attach a detached entity.

What might be a problem is that you need concrete entity Spring Data repositories. So you can't have a `productRepository` but a `memoryRepository` and `processRepository` instead.

So you can get a `Memory` entity:

```
Product memory = memoryRepository.findOne(1L);
```

If you modify the attached entity in the same Hibernate Session, the [dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) will synchronize changes with the database.

If the entity is sent to an HTTP Session and merged back in another transaction then you need to use the actual repository:

```
memoryRepository.save(memory);
```

You can have your repositories extend an interface giving the supported entity class and then use an [automatic scanning mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/why-i-like-spring-autowired-for-list-types/) to have a `Map<Class, CrudRepository>`, so that based on the product type, you can fetch the associated repository.